Godot4: MultiplayerSpawner not replicating nodes on SpawnPath -> add_child()
When an enemy dies in this game, the following code runs to generate loot if the client is the server:
if multiplayer.is_server():
    await get_tree().create_timer(0.2).timeout
    drop_loot(loot_pool)
    queue_free()

...

func drop_loot(for_loot_pool):
    $/root/Root/LootManager.drop_loot_at_position(global_position, for_loot_pool)

And then my LootManager object, with the following node structure:
LootManager
|_ LootRoot (set as spawn path of MultiplayerSpawner)
|_ MultiplayerSpawner

I'm checking to make sure it's only the server instance that would actually spawn the loot; as to my knowledge that's how adding things to MultiplayerSpawner works.
func _ready():
    loot_spawner.add_spawnable_scene("res://scenes/items/Jewel1.tscn")
    loot_spawner.add_spawnable_scene("res://scenes/items/Jewel2.tscn")


func spawn_loot(loot_path, at_position):
    var loot_scene = load(loot_path)
    var loot_item = loot_scene.instantiate()
    loot_root.add_child(loot_item, true)
    loot_item.global_position = at_position


func drop_loot_at_position(drop_position: Vector3, for_table):
    if multiplayer.is_server() == false: return
    var loot_drops_paths = get_drops(for_table) # returns paths to scenes
    for loot_path in loot_drops_paths:
        spawn_loot(loot_path, drop_position)

MultiplayerSpawner is supposed to replicate scenes added to the spawn path to peers right? In my case, these items only show up on the client that is_server() == true
What could I change to get these to actually show up on the other clients?

Ah, in asking the question I have found the answer.
Turns out the items were spawning; they just were getting different positions. As you can see, in spawn_loot I was setting the global_position of the item, but this was only running on the server.
So the client acting as server and the other client would see them in two different places (the client would just see them at origin (0, 0, 0)
The fix I went with for this was to make the position set an RPC on the item object itself:
func spawn_loot(loot_path, at_position):
    var loot_scene = load(loot_path)
    var loot_item = loot_scene.instantiate()
    loot_root.add_child(loot_item, true)
    loot_item.set_loot_item_position.rpc(at_position)

...

# Item.gd
@rpc("authority", "call_local")
func set_loot_item_position(to_position):
    global_position = to_position

Thank you SO rubber ducky!
